# Weird ephemeral error for ManyToMany fields during Django migrations

Tags: django, many-to-many, database-migration, django-1.9

There's this weird error that my company has been facing since the last few months. We have a ton of `model`s in our code and a lot of them have `ManyToMany` fields in them. For ex -

```
class TypeMapping(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    from_config_type = models.ManyToManyField(Type, blank=True, related_name="from_config_type")
    to_config_type = models.ManyToManyField(Type, blank=True, related_name="to_config_type")
```

Sometimes, and only sometimes, after a deployment, we start getting errors like these

```
Error :- Cannot resolve keyword 'to_config_type' into field. Choices are: <a long list of choices which does include 'to_config_type'.
```

We use AWS and this error only crops up sometimes, and that too, only on one server instance we have.

I know that `related_name` and `field_name` should not be the same, but that's for abstract base classes. The above model isn't one.

I've racked my head at this and so have my teammates but we couldn't land on anything.

Can anyone help us on this?

Sample query -

```
sample_type = Type.objects.get(pk=322)
TypeMapping.objects.filter(from_config_type=sample_type)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your reference to abstract base classes. Whatever the class, related_name and field_name should not be the same.

Comment: It is written in the docs that the problem only arises for `related_name` in abstract base classes. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)

Comment: But what happens if those two names are indeed the same?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that this **only** gives a problem for abstract classes. It says that it **will** happen for abstract classes if you don't do the trick mentioned further down. It still says that the related_name **must always** be unique.